# Python: Graphing many graphs at the same time (matplotlib)

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that takes a parameter p and then outputs a graph with plt.plot().

However I'd like to pass a list of many p values and have it plot all the graphs at the same time (e.g. like a matrix of graphs, I don't know what it's actually called. A sort of grid of many graphs). How can this be done?

For example this is my current function (simplified):

```
def graph(p):
    x = np.array(get x values from p here) #pseudocode line
    y = np.array(get y values from p here) #pseudocode line

    plt.title("title")
    plt.ylabel("ylabel")
    plt.xlabel("xlabel")
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label = "some label")
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: take a look at [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

Comment: I couldn't get subplots working the way I wanted it to and figured it wasn't what I needed -- how would I use this properly to do what I need it to?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: I wasn't able to try anything because I had no idea how to apply it to my current plots

Comment: You want to look at the OO interface, not the state machine interface for matplotlib.  You will get better help if you provide _some_ base for the code in your question, even if it is just psudo-code

Comment: I updated the OP with my current function

Comment: One more hint for writing good questions, replace `x` and `y` with `arange` and `random` with sensible paramters, it makes your code copy-and-paste able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def graph(p, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    x = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, 1024)
    y = np.sin(x) + p

    ax.set_title("title")
    ax.set_ylabel("ylabel")
    ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
    ax.plot(x, y, 'ro', label = "some label")
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')

# Number of subplots. This creates a grid of nx * ny windows
nx = 3
ny = 2

fig = plt.gcf()
# Iterate over the axes
for j in xrange(nx * ny):
    t_ax = fig.add_subplot(nx, ny, j + 1)  # Add one for 1-indexing
    graph(j, t_ax)

plt.show()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
```

[See here for guide on `tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

Comment: "name 'gcf' is not defined" (I am using import matplotlib.pyplot as plt )

Comment: should be `plt.gcf()`.  I work in ipython with a whole bunch of stuff imported directly into the name space and some times I forget to re-append `plt`

Comment: The text problems are still the same as the other answer -- the legends are big, axes numbers are big, titles overlap the axes of the graphs above them, etc. Is there a way to either autoscale the text when shrinking down a subplot like this or to add padding between graphs?

Comment: yes, see link.  If you have more problems, you should open a new question.

Comment: Although I called plt.tight_layout() before plt.show(), not sure if that matters (as opposed to calling fig.tight_layout() after show())

Comment: `tight_layout` involves a bit of magic, it worked better for me in this order.  It _might_ also be slightly backend-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many plots you want, you can do something like this

```
def graph(p):
    x = np.array(get x values from p here) #pseudocode line
    y = np.array(get y values from p here) #pseudocode line

    plt.title("title")
    plt.ylabel("ylabel")
    plt.xlabel("xlabel")
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label = "some label")
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

    # Removed the show line from here
    # plt.show()


# Number of subplots. This creates a grid of nx * ny windows
nx = 3
ny = 2

# Iterate over the axes
for y in xrange(nx):
    for x in xrange(ny):
        plt.subplot(nx, ny, y * ny + x + 1)  # Add one for 1-indexing
        graph(p)

# Finally show the window
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, this came really close! Is there a way to have it fix the scaling of the labels and axes and such? They seem to be the same size as before and it looks odd, but thank you for this so far!

Comment: You really should grab the `axes` object that `subplot` returns, and then modify `graph` to be `graph(p, ax)` so you don't end up reliant on global state.

Comment: and if you have a new-enough version of matplotlib tight-layout will fix some of the layout issues.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not a CS person, would you be able to explain more what you mean by that? Possibly with an example?